# Data analysis with NULL value in the table SQL

Tags: sql

The objective here is to find customers whose purchasing habit changes over time in terms of change of percentage of certain order category in total num of order categories in corresponding year (especially decreasing trend). I have worked out the a table containing columns like

```
CUSTOMERNAME, ORDERCATEGORY, 2014PERCENT, 2015PERCENT, 2016PERCENT
```

However, since in each year there are some customers who haven't buy anything, there are some NULL value in the table. So I was wondering in this case (every individual shows different order pattern), how could I find a way to calculate something like differences of percentage in different years? Or is there any other way for me to tackle it?

[image]

Comment: Look into the SQL NVL, IFNULL, or ISNULL function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `COALESCE()` function to turn the `NULL` values to `0`:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERNAME, ORDERCATEGORY,
       COALESCE(2014PERCENT, 0) as 2014PERCENT,
       COALESCE(2015PERCENT, 0) as 2015PERCENT,
       COALESCE(2016PERCENT, 0) as 2016PERCENT
FROM t;
```

For most analytical purposes, zeroes are more appropriate than `NULL`s in summary data.

Comment: This makes sense! Thanks! I will try it~

Answer (score 0):

You ca try using IS NULL to check whether it has null values or not.

```
SELECT column_names
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IS NULL;
```

Comment: To check whether there is NULL value is one thing, but more importantly, considering different individual cases, it is hard to compare percentage in different years.